# Precompact set of metric space has fundamental sequence.

Tags: functional-analysis, algebraic-topology

So, let's define "precompact set".

Precompact set $A$ in a metric space is set, if its closure is compact in $X$.
From using a test compactness, the set of points of a complete metric space is precompact if and only if it's totally bounded. 
The set $A$ of points of a metric space $\left (X,\rho \right )$ is called totally bounded if for any $\varepsilon>0$ in M there exists a finite $\varepsilon$-net.

Okey, but I don't understand the fact, which I must prove.

> M $\subset$ $\left (X,\rho \right )$ is precompact $\Leftrightarrow$  $\forall (x_{n}) \in M  $  $\Rightarrow$ $\exists $ $(x_{n_{k}})$ - fundamental

What should I use for proof this statement?
Can I use tests compactness for compact set? But I don't see difference between compact and precompact set of metric space..

Comment: It does not make sense to ask whether a space $(X, \rho)$ is precompact. The definition is about subsets of a metric space, so you want some "precompact inside $X$".

Comment: Sorry, I make mistake. I have corrected.

Comment: Do you know that in a metric space $X$ a compact set $M$ is the same as sequentially compact (every sequence in $M$ has a subsequence convergent to a point of $M$)? With this characterization, the proof is straightforward.